# Manifest V3 Policy Question - Is this loading a configuration or building an interpreter?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The newest Manifest V3 policy for Google Chrome states the following:

> Building an interpreter to run complex commands fetched from a remote
> source, even if those commands are fetched as data

I am building a Google Chrome plug in that helps automate logging in for our enterprise users. Sometimes, the websites we support change their layouts or their login flows. When we detect this scenario, I want to be able to send an updated configuration to our extension from our servers so that our extension is aware of the new steps to execute to login.

Would this general flow be a violation of the above policy?

Appreciate any feedback on this!

Best,

Cerby Extensions

Comment: You should ask on https://crbug.com or in the [extensions group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions) where an official representative with a `@chromium.org` email will answer.

Comment: Thank you! @wOxxOm I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Can you please post the result of the suggested enquires here?

Comment: @darbid Yes, absolutely